# Groupby one column and find duplicates from another column then return indications in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a small dataset `df` as follows, I need groupby `floor`, find duplicates in `room` then return `check` column in Pandas:

```
   id  floor   room
0   1      1  101.0
1   2      1  102.0
2   3      2  201.0
3   4      2  201.0
4   5      2  202.0
5   6      3    NaN
6   7      3  201.0
7   8      3  301.0
```

I would like to use code as follows since there are many other columns to check:

```
a = np.where(condition, None, 'duplicates')
# b = np.where(df.area.str.contains('^\d+$', na = True), None,
#                                  'area is not a numbers')  
f = (lambda x: ';'.join(y for y in x if pd.notna(y)) 
                if any(pd.notna(np.array(x))) else np.nan )
df['check'] = [f(x) for x in zip(a)]
```

The expected result will like this:

```
   id  floor   room       check
0   1      1  101.0         NaN
1   2      1  102.0         NaN
2   3      2  201.0  duplicates
3   4      2  201.0  duplicates
4   5      2  202.0         NaN
5   6      3    NaN         NaN
6   7      3  201.0         NaN
7   8      3  301.0         NaN
```

How could I modify the condition code? Thanks for your help at advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `np.where` with `duplicated`. Instead of grouping by floor you can look for duplicates of a subset of `['floor', 'room']` and pass `keep=False` to flag both duplicates:

```
df['check'] = np.where(df.duplicated(['floor', 'room'], keep = False), 'duplicates', np.NaN)
df
Out[1]: 
   id  floor   room       check
0   1      1  101.0         nan
1   2      1  102.0         nan
2   3      2  201.0  duplicates
3   4      2  201.0  duplicates
4   5      2  202.0         nan
5   6      3    NaN         nan
6   7      3  201.0         nan
7   8      3  301.0         nan
```

Comment: Maybe use `None` instead of `np.NaN`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use transform:

```
df["count"] = df.groupby(["floor", "room"]).transform("count")
```

result:

```
   id  floor   room      count
0   1      1  101.0        1.0
1   2      1  102.0        1.0
2   3      2  201.0        2.0
3   4      2  201.0        2.0
4   5      2  202.0        1.0
5   6      3    NaN        NaN
6   7      3  201.0        1.0
7   8      3  301.0        1.0
```